# Android Studio Dependency 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 31 or higher

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

currently my sdk version is 29.
I've added firebase imports in gradle and it works fine for the database and firestore.
But when I add the import for the firebase auth I get this error.

```
One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:
```

Dependency 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 31 or higher.
Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-29'

I've tried importing with no version (in firebase documentation firebase bom select the version automatic and I've tried setting the version to implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6' but I get the same error)

Here is a piece of my gradle file:

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
```

The problem is the firebase-auth because if I comment the line of code the app runs fine

Comment: So did you try following the error message and set your 'compileSdkVersion' to 31 or higher?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yeah but I need my compileSdkVersion to be 29. And from the documentation the sdk version 29 is supported by all of my library needed. So this is why I was a bit confused when it asked me the sdk to be 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by setting the implementation of firebase bom to the version of 29:

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')